# Programmaticaly detect if python code is being under test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

How can python program know if it is being tested? For example:

```
def foo():
    if foo_being_tested:
        pseudorandom()
    else:
        random()
```

When in test, program should use pseudorandom sequence to be able to compare with C code version of the program and in regular execution random from `numpy` should be used.

Comment: Could you precise why you need such a behavior? I believe it is very dangerous: how can you test 'do_regular_stuff'?

Comment: @Simpom I have added an explanation to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, not without inspecting the call stack.

*Generally* speaking, you should not do this at all; by altering your code when tested you are not correctly testing your code.

Instead, you'd use mocking to replace any parts your code uses (anything used by the code under test but not part of it). For your specific example, you'd mock out `random()`; on Python 3.3 and up you can use [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html), available as [`mock` on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) for other Python versions, or you can just manually swap out `module_under_test.random` for the duration of the test.

You could also set an environment variable in your unittests to make it explicit you are running a test, but ideally that should be avoided.

Comment: I have considered using mockup but wanted to explore this option also as it had a potential to be more elegant. Inspecting stack is definitely taking elegance out of this option :)

Comment: Accepted, and in this special case the solution was to use the same random number generator from c and initalize it with the same seed in python and in c.